# "Converse" of Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I've stumbled upon this unusual "converse" of BC Lemma. The usual one being the one stated for example here: [Proof of the converse Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833047/proof-of-the-converse-borel-cantelli-lemma)

The unusual one being:

If $P(\lim \sup A_n) = P(A_n \ \ \text{i.o.})= 0\ $  (infinitely often) and $ \{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a family of independent events then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n) < \infty
$$

---

My doubt here comes as why is this the converse and where does the independence have to be used on the result as I haven't used it in my proof, but as always, if it weren't necessary it wouldn't be stated in the first place

---

I've changed my proof to force myself to use independence as not doing so makes the statement false (David C. Ullrich's comment):

Let's suppose to reach a contradiction that $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n) = \infty
$$

Now, we know $P(\lim_n \sup A_n) = 0$ so $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = 1$

But $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(\cap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n^c)$

Then, $P(\cap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n^c) = \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}P(A_n^c) = \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}(1-P(A_n) \leq \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}e^{-P(A_n)} = e^{-\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}P(A_n)} = 0$

Where the first equality holds since $A_n$ being independent also holds for $A_n^c$, and the inequality is true since $1-x \leq e^{-x} \  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Implying that $P(\lim_n \sup A_n^c) = 1$ so $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = 0$ contradicting the initial hypothesis.

Comment: Post your proof please. We are just used to call it the converse while it's not the actually converse proposition. Far as I know, independence is necessary. So if you don't use it, maybe some details are missed.

Comment: because of the added assumption it is only a "partial" converse. As limsup A_n is a tail event its probability is either 0 or 1. So P(limsup A_n) ≠ 1 iff its = 0

Comment: Consider $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Let $A_n=(0,1/n]$. Then $\limsup A_n=\emptyset$... (so your proof is wrong - if you want opinions on where the error is you need to show us the argument).

Comment: I posted my corrected proof using the independence

Comment: I don't use the "converse" language here.  I say there are two directions for Borel-Cantelli: an easy direction (not requiring independence) and a hard direction (requiring independence).

Comment: There is  a rather interesting version of a "converse" Borel-Cantelli theorem that has some applications in Harmonic Analysis. In fact, David C. Ulrich used this sort of result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2617681/121671) in his solution to a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2612281/121671) [solved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2617435/121671) by GuieppeNegro. The results states that if $(E_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ are measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ with $\sum_n\lambda(E_n)=\infty$,, then there are translates $(F_n=E_n+r_n)$ such that $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}=\limsup_nF_n$ a.s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer was given as correct by a professor of mine that checked it, so I'm posting it.

Let's suppose to reach a contradiction that $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n) = \infty
$$

Now, we know $P(\lim_n \sup A_n) = 0$ so $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = 1$

But $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(\cap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n^c)$

Then, $P(\cap_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n^c) = \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}P(A_n^c) = \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}(1-P(A_n)) \leq \Pi_{n=N}^{\infty}e^{-P(A_n)} = e^{-\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}P(A_n)} = 0$

Where the first equality holds since $A_n$ being independent also holds for $A_n^c$, and the inequality is true since $1-x \leq e^{-x} \  \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Implying that $P(\lim_n \sup A_n^c) = 1$ so $P(\lim_n \inf A_n^c) = 0$ contradicting the initial hypothesis.